# Selenium clicking through a list that opens new element

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I need some help figuring out how to iterate through a table where clicking the element doesn't open a new page, but opens something like a blade in Microsoft Azure, or a navigation drawer, that covers the list.

I only want to click specific elements in the list, which I'm able to parse just fine and click the first element I want, but I'm running into a Stale Element Reference Exception in my for loop.

```
# this is single column table with ~20 rows
elements=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//table[@class='table table-striped FWTable']/tbody//tr//td[2]")))
    for ele in elements:
        if (".mp3" in ele):
            clickElement(ele) # this opens the blade that covers the table
        # this is where it blows up with exception on 2nd iteration
        # do something here to refresh the DOM? refresh the page and put a wait here?


def clickElement(ele):
    # no problems interacting with the fields on the open blade
    saveBtn = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//[@id="app"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/span[2]')
    saveBtn.click() # this closes the blade and returns to the for loop
```

I've looked at other posts for looping through tables, but mine is causing the DOM to need refreshing and I've been struggling to find how to handle the stale element exception.

I could probably get away with refreshing the page and then make sure to have an adequate wait time, assuming the elements list remains valid.

Is this a sound way to iterate through a table/list in selenium or is there something more suited for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're facing `StaleElementReferenceException`, because after click you DOM is updated. So you need to get elements array again.
You can achieve this via waiting for element staleness and then getting new elements array.

```py
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,20)
elements = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//table[@class='table table-striped FWTable']/tbody//tr//td[2]")))

for index in range(len(elements)):
    element = elements[index]
    if (".mp3" in element):
            clickElement(elemenet)
            #if you need, there you can click back, etc., if there was transition to another page
            wait.until(EC.staleness_of(element))
            elements = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//table[@class='table table-striped FWTable']/tbody//tr//td[2]")))
```